# to use count of rows displayed in details section to suppress header section

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

i am taking the count of rows displayed in details section in a counter variable. how can i use this count value in group header so that i can suppress header if count=0

Answer (score 0):

First, Crystal can't normally display a group header if there are no individual records for that group. An exception would be if the incoming dataset was specifically set up with rows that are nearly blank.

1. In the **section expert**, go to the details section.
2. Under the **group header** section, open the custom formula editor for the **suppress** option.
3. Enter `if count({keyfield},{group})=0 then True else False`. This counts the number of occurrences of {keyfield} per {group}. If the count is 0, then the group header is suppressed.